# how to print only those rows when columns values are not identical?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a big file counting genotype input file. Here is the first few lines:

```
LocusID f nAlleles x y
2L:8347 1 2 44.3166 -12.2373
2L:8347 1 2 39.2667 -6.8333
2L:31184 1 2 39.2667 -6.8333
2L:31184 1 2 39.2667 -6.8333
2L:42788 1 2 39.2667 -6.8333
2L:42788 1 2 39.2667 -6.8333
2L:42887 1 2 39.2667 -6.8333
2L:42887 1 2 39.2667 -6.8333
```

The first column is locus ID and for each locus I have two rows with identical locus IDs. I want to keep only those which column x and column y are not qual for each locus.

here is my desired output from the above example

```
out
2L:8347 1 2 44.3166 -12.2373
2L:8347 1 2 39.2667 -6.8333
```

Any idea how I can do it?

Comment: Have you got a MWE that you can share with us?

Comment: MWE????????????

Comment: This isn't hard to do but column x and column y aren't equal for any of the values in the LocusID column in your file. Can you be more clear on what it is that you want? Do you just want to print out those two particular rows?

Comment: WME -> Minimum Working Example (?) That would only be relevant if you were demonstrating a bug in some code you thought should work, surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
    next
}
NR % 2 {
    split(prev,p)
    if ( ( p[f["x"]] != $(f["x"]) ) || ( p[f["y"]] != $(f["y"]) ) ) {
        print prev
        print
    }
}
{ prev = $0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2L:8347 1 2 44.3166 -12.2373
2L:8347 1 2 39.2667 -6.8333
```

Comment: (a) I'm not convinced the data actually includes the header line shown: if it's just window dressing on the OP, you would need to hard-code the column names in a BEGIN section to rescue your logic. (b) It's kind of obfuscated: seems to me you save the second of each pair of lines to no purpose, as the next cycle stores on top of it again.

Comment: All we have to go on is what the OP provides. If you're not convinced the header line is present in the real data then why be convinced `x` is field 4 and not field 27 ? No, it's far from obfuscated, it's trivial, idiomatic awk code, and storing that line makes sense since the variable `prev` always holds the previous line and the fact we don't use it except in the current problem context is irrelevant, it'll be there for if/when we need to enhance the script later.

Comment: I figured out the interpretation of the OP that most closely agreed with the sample data and results. However, the fact that the OP chose to label the columns by name in his post for reference purposes does not necessarily mean those labels are part of the file data shown. I'd say that, being as it is not actually CSV but a home-brew, chance that header line is present is less that 50%. Maybe OP cares enough to tell us.

Comment: You may be right of course and she should clarify her needs but I think there's a clue in her previous question [how-to-select-columns-in-a-file-by-the-column-name-in-a-txt-file-in-unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529060/how-to-select-columns-in-a-file-by-the-column-name-in-a-txt-file-in-unix).

Comment: Let's hope Anna is consistent. I had missed that previous question. I had a client whose off-shore support sent me hundreds of files, each set in a different format every month. I did the column name trick, but they also varied the column names, so I ended up making a dictionary of synonyms and a Similar-to analysis, all in awk. I'm reasonably sure they did this deliberately, because they wanted the work I contracted for.

Answer (score 0):

Tested. If the column headers are NOT really present in the file, delete the BEGIN line.

```
#! /bin/bash

AWK='''
BEGIN { getline; }
{
    R1 = $0; getline R2;
    split (R1, V1); split (R2, V2);
    if (V1[4] != V2[4] || V1[5] != V2[5]) {
        print R1; print R2;
    }
}
'''

    awk "${AWK}" myFile
```

Comment: This relies strictly on exactly two rows per LocusID throughout the file. It would be more robust if it grouped by LocusID and checked that (a) the group size was at least 2 rows, and (b) Every row in the group had identical x and y values (actually the converse of this). That would just need a 2-D array, plus dealing with the look-ahead when you have read the next row that is the start of the next group, or EOF. Might post that tomorrow.

Comment: Getline isn't necessary or appropriate for a simple task like this, could fail in unexpected ways and would make future enhancements difficult. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. Also using an awk script stored in a shell variable introduces unnecessary complexity and even if you were going to do that 2 of the 3 `'`s in each `'''` are redundant. Finally - don't use all upper case variable names in shell or awk to avoid clashing with builtin names, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a comment to Ed Morton, but too large and possibly of more general interest.

I wrote a simple five-minute job for an OP who couldn't get started, after seeing two unhelpful comments. I'm not all that impressed with your reference, which contains alternatives that would induce vomiting, like:

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/3/{c=5}/4/{print "Eureka!"}' file
```

I did point out that better techniques are possible, and I posted and tested code.

Of course getline is not necessary here, but it does provide a certain symmetry to the operations. If you rely on awk cycle, you end up using something like FNR % 2 == 1 to deal with the strictly alternating lines. That sucks, hence I would prefer to ignore the OPs "two rows" and group lines by the LocusID, for generality.

I dignify awk scripts by posting them in shell variables because they read better. I detest a large awk code put on the command line and folded in odd places. Also, that really hacks off SysAdmins because the whole awk shows up in a ps -ef and scruffs up the output (on SunOS it used to crash ps because it had a fixed max line length).

My usual idiom to prevent this in bash would be:

```
awk -f <( echo "${AWK}" )
```

which ps lists as awk -f /dev/fd/63, conveniently hiding my proprietary code from the inquisitive.

I never split the shell command from the awk: I never use a .awk file. One of two bad things will happen:

(a) You provide the .awk file, and expect the user to type the awk command (possibly including '-F|' or some other option), and he WILL get it wrong.

(b) You provide the user with a .sh and a .awk, and there is an update issue, and he ends up with an inconsistency between the files.

For the same reasons, if I need to provide a man page, I embed it in the script itself, as functions called Usage and Help, containing Here documents.

I am well aware that ''' ... ''' is not necessary. However, I got fed up with posting single-quoted solutions and having people think "Missing quote there, I will fix it", screwing up my tested post, and then complaining it didn't work. Obfuscating it with a couple of empty strings deters people from messing with it, and increases visibility.

After 40 years in Unix, I know the reserved variables in shell and awk. I have good rules for naming, but for a trivial problem I prefer to use terms the OP may intuit. Two rows, two vectors. I use caps for many shell variables for visibility to distinguish them from keywords. Anybody can write keywords: almost all bugs are because coders don't see the data, they don't accentuate the role of variables.

Getline does not fail in unexpected ways for me, because I know what to expect. You might not like the idioms I use, but that doesn't make them wrong. They are solutions to issues I have seen over many years.

Comment: I've also been programming for 40 years but apparently have had different experiences from you. With your getline solution you couldn't simply add a 1-line `{print | "cat>&2"}'` statement to print every input line to stderr for tracing execution or add any other functionality you want executed for every line, it would silently behave as if the last line was duplicated if the 2nd of the pair was missing. I don't know what you're referring to about people saying you have missing quotes when you use `'` vs `'''`.  Your statement starting with ` If you rely on awk cycle` is wrong, etc. etc.

Comment: I said "If you rely on awk cycle, you end up using something like FNR % 2 == 1", and your code includes "(NR-2) % 2", and I'm wrong? And in what world do you need to subtract 2 from something and have it make a difference to the result of % 2?

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. That's a choice I made for this specific case where there's pairs of lines, not the appropriate implementation in general for the case where there can be more than 2 lines per block. You're right, I don't need to subtract 2, I didn't put much thought into that I'll fix it now, thanks.

Comment: The ''' thing used to happen regularly. When I used AWK=' and a multiline code, the OP would think they saw an unbalanced quote, add a second quote, and then flame me for posting untested code that produced a shower of errors (being as it was reading awk code as shell). They didn't seem to react to triple quotes. I partly got the idea from Python.

Answer (score 0):

My advice: turn the spaces into commas so you have a CSV, and then *load it into a database.*

Using `psql` and Postgres and the file you have given as `temp.csv` this looks like so:

```
postgres=> create temp table d (locusid text, f int, n_alleles int, x float, y float);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=> \copy d from program 'tr " " , < temp.csv' with (format csv, header true)
COPY 8
postgres=> table d;
 locusid  | f | n_alleles |    x    |    y     
----------+---+-----------+---------+----------
 2L:8347  | 1 |         2 | 44.3166 | -12.2373
 2L:8347  | 1 |         2 | 39.2667 |  -6.8333
 2L:31184 | 1 |         2 | 39.2667 |  -6.8333
 2L:31184 | 1 |         2 | 39.2667 |  -6.8333
 2L:42788 | 1 |         2 | 39.2667 |  -6.8333
 2L:42788 | 1 |         2 | 39.2667 |  -6.8333
 2L:42887 | 1 |         2 | 39.2667 |  -6.8333
 2L:42887 | 1 |         2 | 39.2667 |  -6.8333
(8 rows)

postgres=> select d.* from d join d as d2 on d.locusid = d2.locusid and (d.x != d2.x or d.y != d2.y);
 locusid | f | n_alleles |    x    |    y     
---------+---+-----------+---------+----------
 2L:8347 | 1 |         2 | 44.3166 | -12.2373
 2L:8347 | 1 |         2 | 39.2667 |  -6.8333
(2 rows)
```

Comment: This isn't much use if your purpose is to pipe a subset of the original data into another program for further processing, which is common with bioinformatics tasks.   Databases like postgresql have a lot of good uses, and can greatly simplify complex query operations - but that simplification is offset by a) the time and effort involved in importing the data into a database and b) having to write additional code to format the output so that it can be fed into another program.

Comment: Sometimes (quite often) flat text files and text processing tools are enough - not everything needs a relational database.  The cost (in time and effort) to import a flat text file into a database is only justifiable if you need to make **lots** of queries on the same data, not just perform a one-off extraction or summary or reduction or whatever.

Comment: @cas perhaps, but point b is not the case as psql can easily output csv format.

Comment: Bioinformatics tools generally don't process CSV, or connect directly to a database like postgres.  They process space or tab separated text files, like the OP posted.   Going through a database, you have to create a table structure, import the data, run your query and output to a CSV file (or space/tab-separated), and then feed that into some other program.  Like i said, postgres has its uses (and for certain kinds of taks a db is irreplaceable) but it's overkill and over-complication for a job like this.